# コメントするのに信用度が50点必要なのはなぜ？他の方法は？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案

信用度が50点に満たないユーザーは投稿にコメントを追加することができません。

- この制限があるのはなぜ？
- 回答として投稿してもいいですか？
- 追加情報なしでは回答できない時は？

> 関連情報：
>
> - [コメント権限 - ヘルプセンター](/help/privileges/comment)
> - [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756) （コメントに関する仕様をまとめた英語版のFAQ）
>
> このFAQは Meta Stack Exchange の [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173) を元にしています。

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## この制限があるのはなぜですか？

新規ユーザーの方々の中にも的確なコメントができる人がいて、50点の信用度制限によってそれらのコメントを失っていることは理解しています。

とはいえ、誰でもコメントできるようにすることには、そのメリットをはるかに上回るデメリットがあることを、StackExchangeネットワークの経験と歴史が物語っています。

- なによりもスパム投稿の問題があります。自動フィルタは完全ではありません。
- 真面目なコメントであっても、その大半は「私も同じ問題を抱えています」とか「私もそう思います」といったものです。このようなコメントはQ&Aサイトとしては価値がないので、手動で削除しなければなりません。
- コメントのモデレーションは困難です。StackExchangeのサイトが持つ、投票・通報・レビューといったコミュニティによるモデレーション機能は質問や回答には効果的に働きますが、コメントには向きません。マイナス投票やクローズ投票もできなければ、検索すらできません（できるようにするつもりもありません）。
- StackExchangeにおけるコメントの地位は低く、将来にわたって有用な情報を保持するようには設計されていません。何らかの理由でばっさり削除されるかもしれません。原則として、**本当に重要な情報は回答の中に含めるべき**です。

良い回答を投稿すれば、50点なんてすぐです。あるいは既存の質問や回答に対して[編集提案](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)をするのもよいでしょう。この場合2点ずつ信用度が得られます。

---

## だけど今すぐコメントしたいんです！

### 「コメントを回答として投稿してもいいですか？」

**ご遠慮下さい。**

質問と回答はこのサイトの基本機能ですから、信用度を問わず全てのユーザーが使えます。

だからといってコメント制限を回避するために使っていいわけではありません。**回答として投稿されたコメントは削除の対象になります。**

質問のあいまいな点を指摘したり、ほかの人の回答にコメントしたい場合は、必要な信用度が貯まるまで待たなければいけません。

### 「どうやったら良い回答が書けますか？」

[**質問に対する完全で有効な回答**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) が書けそうなら、そのまま回答として投稿して構いません。例えば既存の回答に間違いを見つけた場合、そのことを指摘して補足するのは構いませんが、代わりの解決策を提示するなどして**あなたの回答が単独で成立するようにしてください。** 大抵はコメント欄からのコピペでは済まないはずです。

### 「今わかっている情報だけでは良い回答が書けません！」

完全無欠でなくとも、質問に**答えようとしている**なら、それは立派な回答です。例えば「ひょっとして *X* が原因だとしたら、*Y* で解決できるかもしれません。それで駄目だったら *Z* を試した結果を教えてくれませんか？」といった回答は全く問題ありません。そして情報が追加されたら、回答をより的確なものに修正すればよいのです。**コメントができる場合でも**この方法はお勧めです。

あなたの素敵な回答をお待ちしています！